# How to create a compound property and use it in a jQuery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'd like to be able to create a JS object that has a field that combines existing fields in the object together, but I think I have a context problem for "this" that I'm not sure how to solve.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName)
{
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName  = lastName;

    this.FullName = function ()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

I wish to use FullName is a jquery Template, but haven't had luck.

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="tmplImg">
    {{each people}}
        <li>
            ${FullName}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

I think it can be done somehow because the knockout.js library is able to accomplish it somehow as shown in this tutorial (Step 4).

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9CmkM/):

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    var self = this;
    this.FullName = function() {
        return self.FirstName + ' ' + self.LastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will need it to be a function so that it uses current values. I know it is possible because the knockout.js library is able to accomplish this somehow.

Comment: Clever. Yes that works, thank you! 1 Question. can't you remove the inner function and just do the return statement immediately after defining self?

Comment: Yes, I think I was over thinking this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using your script, I've been able to call FullName and retrieve the full name:

```
var pers = new Person("first", "last");
alert(pers.FullName());
```

Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm trying to use jQuery's templating engine: jquery-tmpl.js and in the template I wish to use something like FullName. My real example is a bit more complex but this demonstrates the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in no way an expert on jQuery Templates, but this works in my tests:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    ${$data.getFullName()}
</script>

function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};

var person = new Person("John", "Doe");

$("#myTemplate").tmpl(person).appendTo("#myOutput");
```

Answer (score 0):

IAbstractDownvoteFactory's answer is a solid answer, and definately deserves an upvote, but I just want to introduce one layer of abstraction beyond his/her answer:

Consider the following helper:

```
function createBoundMethodsFor(obj) {
    var proto = obj.constructor.prototype
    for(var method in proto)
        if(typeof(proto[method]) === 'function')
            obj[method] = function() { return proto[method].apply(obj, arguments); }
}
```

Then lets look at constructor for person again:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;

    createBoundMethodsFor(this)
}

Person.prototype.FullName = function() {
    return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
}
```

This helper loops through all of the `functions` in the object's `prototype`, and builds bound closures for each one, and overrides them as instance methods, but they just proxy through to the prototype method. Using a helper like that might make your life a lot easier as the number of methods on an object become non-trivial.

But be aware that bound methods like this lead to interesting results that you might not expect, for example :

```
var john = new Person("John", "Doe")
var jane = new Person("Jane", "Doe")
var bound = john.FullName

bound() // John Doe
bound.call(jane) // John Doe   (Not Jane like you might expect)

var unbound = john.constructor.prototype.FullName;
unbound() // null
unbound.call(john) // John Doe
unbound.call(jane) // Jane Doe
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3xQz5/)